# Do not run ruby code in render :file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to render an HTML file using `render :file` in my view, but the problem is, if this .html file contains any ruby code, it'll end up being executed and that is something I'm trying to avoid.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to output a simple file, you can do it like this:

```
path = __FILE__
render text: File.read(path).html_safe
```

this writes the current file as output.

Comment: Aye, but that outputs the raw contents of the file. I'd like for the html tags to be interpreted by the browser.

Comment: After digging a bit more into this issue, I found that adding `.html_safe` after `read` makes the HTML display correctly. Could you edit your answer so I can accept it, please?